# Deriving the density function of a exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I am reading a book where the author tries to derive the density function of a exponential variable by the following form:

> Suppose that in a short interval of time $\Delta t$ there is a chance
>   $\lambda \Delta t$ that a event will occur. assuming $\Delta t$ is very
>   small, the chance of more than one event will occur is negligible so
>   that the chance that no event occurs is $(1-\lambda \Delta t)$. It
>   will be assumed that the chance of an event occurring in a short time
>   does not depend on how many events have already occurred.
>
> Is we write $F(t)$ for te probability that no event occurs before time
>   $t$, then the probability that no event occurs before time $F(t+\Delta
> > t)$ if the probability that no event occurs before time $t$ multiplied
>   by the probability that no event occurs between time $t$ and time $(t
> > + \Delta t)$; in symbols ,
>
> $$F(t + \Delta t)= F(t)[1-\lambda \Delta t]$$
>
> $$\frac{F(t + \Delta t) -F(t)}{\Delta t}= -\lambda$$

The author then goes on to use the definition of derivative to conclude the prove, which I fully understand. My problem is with the last two equations. For me there is some error since if we isolate $\lambda$ in the first equation we get

$$\frac{F(t + \Delta t) -F(t)}{F(t)\Delta t}= -\lambda$$

Can someone enlighten me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made no mistake. The passage you quote should lead to the conclusion that 
$$\frac{F(t+\Delta t)-F(t)}{\Delta t}\approx -\lambda F(t).$$
(The first equation mentioned is more or less correct, though of course we do not have *actual* equality. The second equation is just plain wrong.)

Then taking the limit we find that $F'(t)=-\lambda F(t)$. This is the familiar DE of exponential decay, and we get that $F(t)=Ce^{-\lambda t}$ for some constant $C$ which turns out to be $1$.

**Remark:** The choice of $F(t)$ for the name of the probability that no event occurs before time $t$ is very unfortunate. That's because $F(t)$ in this case is $1$ minus the cumulative distribution function. The usual convention is that $F(t)$ is the name of the cdf.

Comment: Indeed the choice was rather bad. The book used another letter but I couldn't remember what it was. Anyways thank you for your help.